# Meaning of "I command you for that"

Tags: meaning, verbs, transitive-verbs

I noticed this somewhere and I have no clue what it means, as I'm not a native speaker. Google hasn't helped out. Does anyone know what this means? (If you need additional context, let me know).

> I command you for that.

Comment: Ironically, it might have been correct with the additional context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a typo or misreading for:

> I **commend** you for that.

Comment: Funny how you depend on Google autocorrect and only notice that when it fails to help you. Thanks!